# Парсинг JSON в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Добрый день.

Нужно распарсить JSON с помощью JavaScript. Делаю вот так:

```
var items = [];
jQuery.getJSON( url, function( json ) {
    jQuery.each(json.posts, function(key, index) {
        loc = index.custom_fields.map_coords[0];
        items.push(loc);
    });
});
console.log(items);
```

Если пытаюсь вывести `console.log(items[0])`, то получаю `undefined`. 
Возможно уже глаз замылился, но я не понимаю, как мне добраться до значений.

Дело в том, что эти значения потом должны использоваться, а я получаю undefined и ничего не могу с этим поделать.

Comment: На момент вызова `console.log` запрос к серверу ещё даже не отправился, потому что он асинхронный. Вы должны поставить `console.log` сразу после `jQuery.each(...);`

Comment: дело даже не в `console.log`, как мне использовать полученные данные потом. так же пихать всё после `each`? не дело же.

Comment: дак вынесите `function(json){...}` в отдельную функцию и там и пишите.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Comment: @zagazat дело, только так и можно делать, в том суть джаваскриптовой асинхронности) Ну и да, вынести всё в отдельную функцию и вызвать её после `each` никто не запрещает

Answer (score 0):

Ну во-первых Ваш код асинхронный. Это значит, что в items будут значения только после того, как выполнится запрос.

То есть Ваш код должен будет выглядеть так:

```
var items = [];
jQuery.getJSON( url, function( json ) {
   jQuery.each(json.posts, function(key, index) {
       loc = index.custom_fields.map_coords[0];
       items.push(loc);
   });
   console.log(items);
});
```

Во-вторых. Не факт что он у Вас выполниться - нужно добавить обработку ошибок:

```
var items = [];
jQuery.getJSON( url, function( json ) {
   jQuery.each(json.posts, function(key, index) {
       loc = index.custom_fields.map_coords[0];
       items.push(loc);
   });
   console.log(items);
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log( "error" );
 })
```

Вопрос как работать с item дальше. 
Вариантов несколько -  через [обещания](https://learn.javascript.ru/promise) или callback-функции.

Пример с callback-функцией.

```
var items = [],
callbacks = $.Callbacks();

callbacks.add(function () {
   console.log(items);
}) 


jQuery.getJSON( url, function( json ) {
   jQuery.each(json.posts, function(key, index) {
       loc = index.custom_fields.map_coords[0];
       items.push(loc);
   });
   callbacks.fire();
   console.log(items);
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log( "error" );
 })
```